# SQL QUERY to count repeats with 2 conditions

Tags: sql, teradata

[image: eg table schema and required output]

To find repeated items only when when it satisfies two conditions. In this example count repeats of item type for each customer_id only when it has order size "Big" and its corresponding date is before other instances. This first condition and repeats can be achieved by using this code.

```
Select Customer_id, Item_Type, COUNT(*) 
from table 
group by Customer_id, Item_Type
having count(*) > 1 and sum(case when Order_Size = 'Big' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

how do I include date aspect as well to this?

Comment: Instead of a screenshot of your spreadsheet, why not a text version we can manipulate? https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select t.customer_id, t.item_type, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when OrderSize = 'Big' then date end) over (partition by customer_id, item_type) as min_big
      from t
     ) t
where date > min_big
group by t.customer_id, t.item_type;
```

Comment: I wanted to add a second condition in case when lets say 'case when (OrderSize='Big' and item_type IN (Select item_type from table2) then date end) over....Its throwing an error saying illegal expression in When clause of case statement. How do I resolve this?

Comment: I have written above query request as new question at Subquery within When Case statement-Error:Illegal expression in When clause within case statement [Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670005/subquery-within-when-case-statement-errorillegal-expression-in-when-clause-with)

Comment: @viji . . . If you have another question, you should ask it as another question not in a comment.  May I ask why you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: I created a seperate question. I did not realise by accepting another answer also this would become unaccepted.Sorry for that!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a window function in a subquery to decide which rows to count, then count them in your main query. Something like:

```
Select
    customer_id, item_type, sum(count_pass) as Count
FROM
    (
        Select Customer_id, 
            Item_Type, 
            CASE 
                WHEN Order_Size = 'Big' THEN 0 
                WHEN MIN(Order_Size) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID, Item_Type ORDER BY DateField ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) = 'BIG' THEN 1 
                ELSE 0
                END as count_pass
        FROM table
    ) subqry
GROUP BY 1,2
```

That big case statement breaks down like:

1. If this record is `'Big'` then ignore it
2. If you order all the records by date for each group of `customer_id`/`item_type` and look at all the records that precede this record, and the `min(order_size)` in that group of records (sorted lexicographically) is `'Big'` then you have a preceding date with big and can count this record
3. Otherwise... you can't count it. Which would just be records with `order_size`=`'small'` without a preceding `'big'`.

Comment: Wanted to include a second condition in case- when query. A new request is written at [Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670005/subquery-within-when-case-statement-errorillegal-expression-in-when-clause-with)